# How can I run a specific type of task off the UI thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

I want to run a function whenever a `recyclerview` binds a view. It's a really long operation, so I have to keep it off the UI thread. I know how to create a thread, but how can I use the same thread to always run the content of the `onBindViewHolder` method on the second thread without creating a new one every time the specific function gets executed ?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder (final Adapter adapter, RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            theMethod(adapter, holder, position);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate "run on the second thread without creating one everytime"?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but since onBindViewHolder is called multiple times, OP wants to run all instances of his code on the same thread, and not make a new one every time.

Comment: `ExecutorService. newSingleThreadExecutor` can be used for threading managing. But I have concerns of the approach, why do you need to do some threading in `onBindViewHolder` method?  You need to remember, that reference to holder on some position may not be valid after finished task due to scrolling.

Comment: Viewholders contain images and I generate palettes on the second thread, because it would slow down the app if I were to create the palettes on the main thread. If you know a better approach then please let me know.

Comment: Sorry for such long delay, I am not sure about your use case. Have you tried using  https://github.com/florent37/GlidePalette ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html), then scheduling work against that thread with a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) created with the HandlerThread's [Looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html).  You will have to remember the shut down the thread at the end of the activity, of course, or it will stick around indefinitely and maybe leak objects.

For example:

```
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("Give Me a Name");
thread.start();
Looper looper = thread.getLooper();
Handler handler = new Handler(mServiceLooper);
// use handler to post work to the thread
```

These lines of code are cribbed directly from [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), which does exactly the same thing you want, except in a service.  Maybe that's even what you actually want to use!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using [Looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html). The main purpose of Looper is this only, to keep the thread alive and waiting for new messages(Runnables).

Here's a sample code from the official documentation :

```
class LooperThread extends Thread {
  public Handler mHandler;

  public void run() {
      Looper.prepare();

      mHandler = new Handler() {
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              // process incoming messages here
          }
      };

      Looper.loop();
  }
```

}

Now, you can post new runnables (messages) to the thread using the handler. Something like this :

```
handler.post(new Runnable()
{
    public void run() {
    //This will be executed on thread using Looper.
}
});
```

Edit :

The method provided above is more of 'do-it-yourself'. There's a special class in android that can do this automatically for you, i.e. [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html). Sample code :

```
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("name");
thread.start();
Looper looper = thread.getLooper();
Handler handler = new Handler(looper);
```

Now you can post runnables to this handler.

Answer (score 1):

Create new thread which can do jobs with a queue.

```
class YourThread extends Thread {
      public List<Job> queue = new ArrayList<>();

      @Override
      public void run(){
           while(queue.size() == 0)
               wait(); // nothing to do, wait...
           Job job = queue.get(queue.size() - 1); // pop queue
           queue.remove(queue.size() - 1);
           dosomething(job);

      }

      public void addJob(....){
           ...
           queue.add(job, 0);
      }
}
```

and `onBindViewHolder`

```
YourThread thread = new ...
thread.start()

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder (final Adapter adapter, RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
     thread.addJob(...);
     // remember that after the job finished, the item may be recycled
}
```